# Comparing named range against a cell value

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-2010

I'll try to make a macro with an If statement in it. But I get the error message

> Sub or Function not defined

The following code is used.

```
Sub whatif()

    If Range("memory") = "data" Then 
Worksheet("Side").Range("B1") = "yes"
    End If

End Sub
```

I figured out the problem is line

```
Worksheet("Side").Range("B1") = "yes"
```

The goal is as follows. 
If the value of cell "memory" is equal to the value of cell "data". Cell B1 of the sheets "Side" gains the value "yes".

When commenting out the other lines it still gives an error. What does need adjustment?

Edit: It does not give an error any more but does not the thing I want it to do.

Comment: change this `Worksheet("Side")` to `Worksheets("Side")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not indexing the collection correctly. Use

```
Worksheets("Side").Range("B1") = "yes"
```

Note the plural.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Worksheet("Side").Range("B1")` to `Worksheets("Side").Range("B1")`.

If the error persists please check that the sub name is not the same as the module name and that you haven't used the same name in another sub as this can cause the definition error.

Read more about this error at
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8y42ktc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have managed to find the other error. Forgot to type Range("data"),

Sub whatif()

```
If Range("memory") = Range("data") Then
    Worksheets("Side").Range("B1").Value = 20
End If
```

End Sub